# how to add "Choose Components" page in NSIS (using macro with .nsh)

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder.

Here I can customise nsis script with pre-defined macros. (https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script)

according to documents, the macros that I can use to customize are: `customHeader`, `preInit`, `customInit`, `customUnInit`, `customInstall`, `customUnInstall`, `customRemoveFiles`, `customInstallMode`.

I want to put a page where I can select what to install. (see below example)
[image]

Which macros should I use to insert this page? And if possible, can I get some example script as well?

Thanks for your tips in advance.

Comment: In real NSIS that is called the components page, no idea how you do it with electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that familiar with the electron-builder, but I can show you how you might do something like this in real NSIS, which I guess should also work for you.

First you will have to define the page like so:

```
Page components SelectComponents
```

Then you would have to define a function with the same name as the page. Here you could for example set the branding image which will be displayed on the Page:

```
Function SelectComponents 
  SetBrandingImage path\image.bmp
FunctionEnd
```

Last you can add your sections. Here you can customize them however you want.
See description from NSIS Manual (https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#sections).

```
Section /o "My section"
  ; Copy files and do other stuff
SectionEnd
```

Let me know if I could help you with your issue.